woocomerce использование acf
Я хочу создать свой магазин. На главной странице я добавил телефон через плагин ACF и он отображается на главной странице (, но как только я перехожу к странице товаров там его нет, подскажите как его добавить на все страницах woocommerce


А как Вы поле добавляли? От скриншотов мало пользы.

Попробуй в шаблоне прописать
echo get_field('поле_с_главной', $page_id);
вместо page_id укажи ID главной страницы

Если тема PHP то нужно аналогичное проделать для каждого шаблона header, вероятно вы сделали только в header.php
Если тема блочная то нужно добавить блок с ввашим теефонов в качестве header и на остальные страницы где телефона нет или добавить теефон в остальные темплейты gutenberg
